# java script reload parent of a parent window on click of any button

Tags: javascript

I want to reload the parent of a parent window in javascript.

My problem is, i opened a new window `onclick` of a link and in child window there is one html page with submit button in `iframe`, i want to reload the main parent window on click of submit button. I dont want to reload the window in which iframe opened, i want to reload the parent of window in which iframe available.

I tried:

```
window.location.reload()
window.opener.location.reload();
window.opener.opener.location.reload();
```

But not able to reload, please suggest what should we do.

Comment: @mkaatman this is not duplicate, in the referenced post, they are reloading the parent tab, i have to reload the parent of parent window.

Comment: `parent.parent.location.reload()`

Comment: @mkaatman, parent.parent.location.reload() it does not work.

Comment: same domain ? use localstorage or serviceworker

Comment: I'd look at a library like iframeresizer and see if it could pass commands to the grandparent.